# Storing NSDate in core data (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdate, nsmanagedobject

I'm new to swift and I'm trying to understand parts of it. I've been working on an app where I need to store a date, and I just can't figure it out.

Any input would be great.

*Code to store date*

```
var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
// Users = Entity in core data
var newuser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users",inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject
// datetostore = attribute of type date
newuser.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "datetostore")
context.save(nil)
```

*Code to get stored data from Core Data*

```
var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
var results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
var end: AnyObject = results[0]
var end2 = end as! NSObject
var end3 = end2 as! NSDate
```

**Please note**: I know the end doesn't really work because that's where I get an error.

Comment: Hint: If you look up the documentation of `setValue(_: forKey:)` then you'll find the corresponding method to *retrieve* a value from an object.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should let Xcode generate `NSManagedObject` subclasses which will allow stronger typing and more concise code. It will generate a class `User` with an attribute `datetostore`.

I would recommend to dispense with the silly names such as `datetostore`. It's clearly a date, and it is obvious that you are storing it. Thus, `date` is quite sufficient.

Finally, from your code it seems that you think the user is the same as the date even though you yourself had just called `setValueForKey` to add the date to the user as an attribute. Think about it, and follow what Martin R recommends.

Without `NSManagedObject` subclass (not recommended):

```
 let aDate = user.valueForKey("date")
```

With subclass: fetch your entities with the right type.

```
let result = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error:nil) as! [User]
// check for empty array, then
let user = result.first
let aDate = user.date
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first time you should create an attribute with Date.
Here is code

```
let date = Date()
let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
dateformatter.format = "dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss"
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

let user = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Example", into: context)
user.setValue(date, forKey: "date")

appDelegate.saveContext()
```